# EF Core как сделать Include только нужных полей?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Доброго времени суток.
Собственно, вопрос в том, как в Include выбрать только нужные поля, а не целые объекты?
О чем говорю: если делать простые запросы без Include, то в Select можно выбрать нужные поля:

```
dbContext.Blogs.Select(x => new Blog { Name = x.Name });
```

Но если у Блога будет вложенное св-во, например, автор, у которого будут поля: Name, Photo, BlogUrl и пр., а мне нужно взять только его имя, то как мне быть? Include(x => x.Author.Name) или Include(x => x.Author).ThenInclude(x => x.Name) не работают и кидаются ошибками.
Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46477084/5045688

Comment: Хорошо, а если у меня вложенность большая? Order -> Order Position -> Category (Name), Status (Name)?
Получаю ошибки, буду рад, если укажете, что делаю не так: https://pastebin.com/rTzpT8hg

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно сделать Include( Positions )

Comment: @Blackmeser Если сделаю Include Positions, то он подгрузит в него все поля, а все поля мне не нужны.

Comment: @LiptonDev Описывайте ещё один dbContext, где будет описано, какие именно поля из класса Positions вам нужны. По-хорошему, для разных условий работы с БД - должны быть отдельные db-контексты, но если проект не большой, производительность не критична, да и лишние поля не являются строковыми - это можно упустить. Есть ещё вариант: ``.Select(p => new FilteredPositionsClass { field1 = p.field1, field2 = field2 ) }``, но я его не пробовал и не знаю каким по факту будет SQL запрос к БД, можете вырежет лишнее, а может и нет.